# Elementor custom query

Tags: wp-query

I am not an expert. I have used a tutorial to write a custom query like this

```
add_action( 'elementor/query/my_query_by_post_types', function( $query ) {
$query->set( 'post_type', [ 'libri', 'post'] );
}   );
```

This has been deployes via snippets plugin. Works fine and filter 'libri' (which is a custom type) and posts. I need to enhance because i need only 'some' post, not all, so I need to filter by post category. Can anybody help to do that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This just requires adding additional parameters to the `query->set()` array... ...it's standard `WP_Query()` stuff.  So you'd essentially be taking this line:

`$query->set( 'post_type', [ 'libri', 'post'] );`

...and expanding it to include a tax query...

```
$tax_query = array(
    'relation' => 'OR',  //can also use 'AND' depends how you want it to work 
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => 1 //put your term id here
    ),
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => 2 //put your term id here
    ),
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => 3 //put your term id here
    )
);
$query->set( 
     'post_type', [ 'libri', 'post'],
     'tax_query', $tax_query
);
```

Answer (score 0):

@Tony Djukic
Your answer was incredibly helpful! But it seems that this structure is an OR:

```
$query->set( 
     'post_type', [ 'libri', 'post'],
     'tax_query', $tax_query
);
```

Based on preliminary testing, it would return anything that is either libri, post, or satisfies the taxonomy filter.

What if we want to AND the post_type and taxonomy - either (libri OR post) AND satisfies the taxonomy filter. How would that work? I think the following is an AND relationship (correct me if I'm wrong):

```
    $query->set( 
        'post_type', [ 'libri', 'post'],
        );  
    $query->set( 
        'tax_query', $tax_query
        );
```

(sorry - not enough points to use comments)